# Python- Function that returns a value

Tags: python, function, return

Im really struggling with this question, can anyone help me write a code for this program? or at least say where am I going wrong? Ive tried a lot but can't seem to get the desired output.

This is the program description: **Python 3 program that contains a function that receives three quiz scores and returns the average of these three scores to the main part of the Python program, where the average score is printed.**

The code I've been trying:

```
def quizscores():
   quiz1 = int(input("Enter quiz 1 score: "))
   quiz2 = int(input("Enter quiz 2 score: "))
   quiz3 = int(input("Enter quiz 3 score: "))

   average = (quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3
   print (average)
   return "average"
   quizscores(quiz1,quiz2,quiz3)
```

Comment: You're just returning the string `"average"`

Comment: As @K.Menyah said, you're returning a string literal rather than the variable `average` simply remove the quotation marks.

Comment: got it, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, you are returning a string, not the variable. Use `return average` instead of `return "average"`. You also don't need the `print()` statement in the function... actually `print()` the function.

If you call a function the way you are doing it, you need to accept parameters and ask for input outside the function to prevent confusion. Use a loop as needed to repeatedly use the function without having to rerun it every time. So the final code would be:

```
def quiz_average(quiz1, quiz2, quiz3):
    average = (quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3
    return average

quiz1 = int(input("Enter Quiz 1 score: "))
quiz2 = int(input("Enter Quiz 2 score: "))
quiz3 = int(input("Enter Quiz 3 score: "))

print(quiz_average(quiz1, quiz2, quiz3))  #Yes, variables can match the parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a string instead of the value. Try `return average` instead of `return "average"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- your function has to accept parameters
- you have to return the actual variable, not the name of the variable
- you should ask those parameters and print the result outside of the function

Try something like this:

```
def quizscores(score1, score2, score3): # added parameters
    average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3
    return average # removed "quotes"

quiz1 = int(input("Enter quiz 1 score: ")) # moved to outside of function
quiz2 = int(input("Enter quiz 2 score: "))
quiz3 = int(input("Enter quiz 3 score: "))
print(quizscores(quiz1,quiz2,quiz3)) # print the result
```

Comment: Worked! Spotted my mistake as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer to the already posted solutions could be to have the user input all of their test scores (separated by a comma) and then gets added up and divided by three using the sum method and division sign to get the average.

```
    def main():
        quizScores()

        '''Method creates a scores array with all three scores separated
        by a comma and them uses the sum method to add all them up to get
        the total and then divides by 3 to get the average.
        The statement is printed (to see the average) and also returned
        to prevent a NoneType from occurring'''

    def quizScores():
        scores = map(int, input("Enter your three quiz scores: ").split(","))
        answer = sum(scores) / 3
        print (answer)
        return answer

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```